# Prism navigation- finding out origin of navigation request?

Tags: prism

I have a viewmodel tied to a view used in a region.  I'm trying to find a way that when that view is navigated to from a particular view (say view A), it does some work internally, like initializing some lists, setting some stuff, whatever.  But if it has been navigated to from view B, it needs to NOT reinitialize everything, and just display the data it already has.

I could pass a parameter I suppose, saying whether this is a new operation or if we are going back to work on the old one, but I thought it would be nicer to be able to state that if we came from this view, we do one thing, and if we came from that one we do another.

If that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `INavigationAware` interface which contains 3 methods. One of these methods is the `OnNavigatedTo` method. There you can access the journal and check the current entry. From there you should be able to determine if it came from View A or View B.

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    var journal = navigationContext.NavigationService.Journal;
    //use journal.CurrentEntry 
}
```

Comment: I do implement this, and it is exactly in OnNavigatedTo() that I need this information.  But as far as I can tell, the Journal does not provide access to where this navigation originated.  It allows you to GoBack(), but not to ask 'Where is back'?  And journal.CurrentEntry is just that, the current entry, i.e. the screen you are now on, not the screen you came from.

Comment: There is one more thing you can look at, and that is State-based navigation. I'm unaware of that part of prism. The only option for you now is implementing your own suggested implementation.

Comment: I just went with the parameter- feels a bit nasty and I wish that I could access that information that I know is in the journal... feature request!